# In Resident Evil 2 (remake as well), why does Marvin not take a green herb?

Tags: resident-evil-2-2019

When replaying RE2 remake, it started to make me realize about the story conflicting with gameplay: the herbs. The character we meet, Marvin, has been bitten by a zombie, and eventually turns. Now when thinking about it, whether we play as Claire or Leon, we get bitten and clawed many times by both zombies and monsters. To cure themselves, green herbs are used to fix them. However, what I do not get is: If there are green herbs all over the place, then why doesn't Leon or Claire bother giving some to Marvin? Sure, it may not be permanent story-wise, but it would give him a fighting chance.

Answer (score 2):

It's never explained in-game, but there is a popular theory (for example, discussed in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/residentevil/comments/i453i0/question_about_green_herbs/)) that for playable characters only bites/infections during cut scenes really happened, so only no damage runs are canonical.

When main characters are damaged during cut scenes they need some kind of cure (not just herbs). For example, during RE3 events:

> Jill got infected by Nemesis and then was unconscious until Carlos managed to get her the vaccine

So to answer your question, there is no sense in giving green herb to Marvin, it's only possible to cure infection with a vaccine, but it's not easily available or even doesn't exist for some viruses.